# How do I call a Javascript function from my Android activity?

Tags: android

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            String url = new String("file:///android_asset/Map.html");
            setContentView(R.layout.leaflet_map);
            this.setTitle("Location Map");

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                        .permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }

            initComponent();

            WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            webSettings.setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
            webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

            // multi-touch zoom
            webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
           /* webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);*/
            myWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

            myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Map.html");
            myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
            myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            mapTextView.setText("Hello Map!!!!");

        }

        public void initComponent(){

            generateId();
            getGeoLocation();
    }
```

**Here I'm trying to call my Javascript function:**

```
    public void getGeoLocation() {

            // creating GPS Class object
            gps = new com.getlocation.periscope.GPSTracker(this);

            // check if GPS location can get
            if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                Log.d("Your Location", "latitude:" + gps.getLatitude()
                        + ", longitude: " + gps.getLongitude());
                Double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                Double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                try{
                myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:latLong('"+latitude+"','"+longitude+"')");
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Exception type"+ex, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            } else {
                // Can't get user's current location
                alert.showAlertDialog(this, "GPS Status",
                        "Couldn't get location information. Please enable GPS",
                        false);
                // stop executing code by return
                return;
            }
            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "latitude:" + gps.getLatitude() + ", longitude: "
                            + gps.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Comment: please help me out to solve this problem.

Comment: Please add more information to your question, it is unclear as to what you are asking. Also, please format your code correctly into code blocks.

Comment: @  Kent Hawkings Sir i want to call my javascript function from my activity class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved it out just by adding this snippet of code.**

```
 myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
       public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            getGeoLocation();
         Bundle getbundle = new Bundle();
         String latString = getbundle.getString("latitud");
         String lotString = getbundle.getString("longitud");

             view.loadUrl("javascript:latLong("+latString+","+lotString+")");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to try something like

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:myfunction(" + param1 + "," +  param2 + ")");
```

where myfunction is your javascript function and param1 and param2 are the elements you would like to pass it.

also make sure that you have enabled javascript in your webview before calling any functions

```
myWebView.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: @user3168029 can you describe what you mean by still not working?  The function is never called?  Have you enabled javascript in your webview (I edited my answer with that code)?

Comment: in oncreate of activity i enabled javascript but still it is not calling this javascript function you can see it above where i posted the code.

Comment: I solved it out just by adding this snippet of code.

 myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                 view.loadUrl("javascript:latLong()");
             }
         });
        
    }

Comment: @user3168029 that means the initial call was happening before the page was finished loading.  Not sure of the point of the latLong() function, but guessing there is a better way to accomplish what you want to do besides adding a call to onPageFinished, especially since you don't need to seem to need any information from the Java side.

Comment: It's likely my  page isn't fully loaded by the time when i am trying to execute the javascript. so that's why I tried this and now it's working. :-)